# How to force (return) to not work until after (retrofit) finished

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, rx-java

hello I'm trying to study dataBinding, mvvm, retrofit and rxjava

in viewModel I used this code

```
private var mainRepository: MainRepository = MainRepository(NetManager(getApplication()))
val isLoading = ObservableField(false)
var mainModel = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<MainModel>>()
private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

fun loadRepositories(id: Int, mainContract: MainContract) {
    isLoading.set(true)
    compositeDisposable += mainRepository
        .getData(id, mainContract)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeWith(object : DisposableObserver<ArrayList<MainModel>>() {

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                //if some error happens in our data layer our app will not crash, we will
                // get error here
            }

            override fun onNext(data: ArrayList<MainModel>) {
                mainModel.value= data
            }

            override fun onComplete() {
                isLoading.set(false)
            }
        })
}
```

and in the MainRepository I used the retrofit with RxJava code

```
private val model = ArrayList<MainModel>()

fun getData(id: Int, mainContract: MainContract): Observable<ArrayList<MainModel>> {

    Api.getData.getMainCategory(id)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe ({
            model.clear()
            model.addAll(it)
            AppLogger.log("testingModel1", model.toString())

        }, {
            AppLogger.log("error", "Failed to load Category : $it")
            mainContract.toast("Failed to load Category")
        })

    AppLogger.log("testingModel2", model.toString())
    return Observable.just(model)
}
```

if you notified that I'm using log to see the output data 
but what I see is that

> AppLogger.log("testingModel2", model.toString())

and

> return Observable.just(model)

are running before

> Api.getData.getMainCategory(id)

so the output in Logcat testingModel2 first and it is empty then testingModel1 and it is have data

so the result data in

> return Observable.just(model)

is nothing

I hope you understand ^_^

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like:

```
fun getData(id: Int, mainContract: MainContract): Observable<ArrayList<MainModel>> {
return Api.getData.getMainCategory(id)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
}
```

but remember to subscribe to it later and add ErrorHandling

And about logs: the problem that actions in `subscribe` block runs only when `Api.getData.getMainCategory(id)` emit something, which could take a time.